# How to configure dialog with field validation in magnolia?

Tags: validation, configuration, dialog, magnolia

I want to add validation for field which should check if the string contains ".html" at the end of it. See my configuration below:
http://screencast.com/t/YgBIKcyU71SQ

But the validation doesn't work. It seems that my configuration of the dialog is incorrect. Could you please help me to figure out where the mistake is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

your pattern is `.html$` This is most likely incorrect. It should be the other way around: `^\.html$`

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `info.magnolia.ui.form.validator.definition.RegexpValidatorDefinition`:

1. Before anything, you want to make sure you regex is correct

   - We use **Java regular expression** (not Javascript or else).
   - Test it independently, i.e. using [regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)
2. Add your [field validation configuration as described in the Magnolia CMS documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Field+validators).

---

#### Example of URL-friendly string validation

That's what my validation does: `Only characters allowed (without the quotes): "a" to "z" (no accents/diacritics allowed & only lower case), "0" to "9", ".", "_", "-".`

That's the regex pattern used: `[a-z0-9._-]+`

Feel free to test it on [regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Add the relevant config to the dialog:
[image: Magnolia CMS: URL-friendly string validation]

Find below the "validators" node config. Save this as in an xml file & import it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sv:node sv:name="validators" xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
    <sv:value>mgnl:contentNode</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>112b96c1-b942-4657-9541-f8776c74d68d</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="jcr:createdBy" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>admin</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:created" sv:type="Date">
    <sv:value>2016-11-17T19:26:09.240+01:00</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:createdBy" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>superuser</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:lastModified" sv:type="Date">
    <sv:value>2016-11-17T19:26:41.771+01:00</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:lastModifiedBy" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>superuser</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:node sv:name="urlCharacters">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
      <sv:value>mgnl:contentNode</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:uuid" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>4d52be80-7211-44d4-8d0a-53a50aed9bc9</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="class" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>info.magnolia.ui.form.validator.definition.RegexpValidatorDefinition</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="errorMessage" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>Only characters allowed (without the quotes): "a" to "z" (without accents), "0" to "9", ".", "_", "-". And only lower case.</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:createdBy" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>admin</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:created" sv:type="Date">
      <sv:value>2016-11-17T19:26:41.772+01:00</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:createdBy" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>superuser</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:lastModified" sv:type="Date">
      <sv:value>2016-11-18T11:30:51.883+01:00</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:lastModifiedBy" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>superuser</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="pattern" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>[a-z0-9._-]+</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
  </sv:node>
</sv:node>
```